# if-else statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to run a code like this:

```
 a = [s,sd,f,r]
 if len(a)>0:
     print("Length is greater then '0'")
 else:
```

What should I put under `else:` if do not want to do something else.

Comment: You can use only `if` without `else`

Comment: @JacksonPro, I am very new in python. Actually, I want to run my code under single condition and otherwise it should not do anything.

Comment: @dimay, Thanks. But what will happen when condition do not meet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want want to do something else, you don't have to use the else part of the statement.

Or you could put

```
else: None
```

Comment: That's great way! Thanks!!

Comment: I'll rather suggest to use
else: pass

Answer (score 5):

Don't put else if you don't need it

Comment: you can bypass the code for later use
else : pass

Answer (score 1):

You can either use only if or you can even put
else :
print("Length is not greater then '0'")